# Regex matching with escape sequences

Tags: python, regex

```
var glob_json =  
{  
    abc
```

I want to match something util the `{` so I used something like below:

```
if re.match(r"(.*)var glob_json =\n{", line, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

but it does not work as in I have somethinglike if the regex match print stmt but it doesn't get exceute. All I want to do is to insert text after the curly braces and before abc.

Comment: What? Could you be more specific than *"does not work"*? `{{` would escape a `{` in a Python format string, but it's not a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: Please show your complete input and the desired output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : I want to match till the { and then add a text after it .

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a [mcve].

Comment: @alecxe: I want  to insert say "gotit" after the { and before abc. So I want my regex to match everything till the '{'

Answer (score 1):

`{` is a metacharacter, so escaping it with `\{` would certainly work. However, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, there may be an easier solution. This pattern matches everything that's NOT `{`

```
[^{]
```

Inside `[]` you do not need to escape (most) metacharacters. If you would like to match multiple things until you hit a `{`, then include the `{` in your match, you can add a `+` or a `*` to that, meaning 'at least one' or 'one or more' respectively. So...

```
if re.match(r"[^{]+\{", line) ...
```

Comment: Not sure then why it is not working:                                                                        'if re.match(r"(.*)var glob_json =[\s\n][{]", text, re.MULTILINE):
                re.sub(r"((.*)var glob_json =[\s\n]*\{)", r"\1{}".format(addText), text)  '                                                                                                                   Further i tried like \{ as well but my file evaluate for true of regex match

Comment: Your code does in fact work for me, but two things to note. 1: re.sub returns a new string, does not alter yours in place. 2: Here is a much simpler version of what you are trying to accomplish: re.sub(r"([^{]+\{)", r"\1{}".format(addText), text). If it doesn't match anything, it'll just return the original string. No need for an re.match.